# Dependency injection of FilesystemCache (SimpleCache) in Symfony 4.0

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am trying to implement a SimpleCache concrete instance in one of my service classes to also allow caching, however I am having some issues at wiring the dependencies.

**config/services.yml**

```
services:
    Psr\SimpleCache\CacheInterface: '@Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\FilesystemCache'
```

**src/Services/Shouter/Sources/Twitter.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Shouter\Sources;

use Psr\SimpleCache\CacheInterface;

class Twitter
{
    /**
     * Cache instance
     * @var Psr\SimpleCache\CacheInterface
     */
    protected $cache;

    public function __construct(CacheInterface $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }
}
```

This is the error that I get:

> You have requested a non-existent service "Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\FilesystemCache".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by adding `Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\FilesystemCache:` in the services.yaml.

[image]